# Create an arraylist with multiple object types from a List<Object[]>

Tags: java

I have the same problem like this post 
[Create an arraylist with multiple object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602601/create-an-arraylist-with-multiple-object-types)

I have a list of objects: `List<Object[]>` and I would have `List<String,Float>`

and I want do like the reply of GV that I make a custom model class with two parameters one `Integer` and other `String`. Then using an `ArrayList` of that object.

but I don't know how can I return this `List` with a multiple types.

Comment: I would recommend having separate lists, one `List<YourCustomModelClass>` and another `List<WhateverYouMayStoreHere>`.

Comment: Would a `Map<String,Float>` work? Otherwise a `List<YourCustomWrapper>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create a `List<String,Float>` (not to mention it's impossible).  Instead, as you allude, you want to create a custom class that *holds* a String and an Integer, and create a list of *that*.

For instance:

```
public class Model {
  private final String name;
  private final int count;

  public Model(String n, int count) { ... }
  public String getName() { ... }
  public int getCount() { ... }
}
```

Now you can create `List<Model>` instances containing the data you need.

```
List<Model> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add(new Model("Jim", 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create an object with properties of type `String` and `Integer` then you can use the `List` of that object type.

```
class YourObject{
   String s;
   Integer i;
   // Contructor(s) and stuff...
}
```

and then:

```
List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
```

O hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

or if you really really want to have a list of objects, when you get  th object from the list you can check its type using instanceof