# Make a list of different objects Java

Tags: java

i'm trying to make a list of different objects.

I know that i can make a list of some object, example:

```
ArrayList<Matrices> list = new ArrayList<Matrices>();
list.add( new Matrices(1,1,10) );
list.add( new Matrices(1,2,20) );
```

But i want to make a list that can do something like this:

```
list.add (new Object1(a,b,c));
list.add (new Object2(e,f));
```

Obviously Object1 and Object2 are different.

Please, give me a hand here.

Comment: What kind of different objects? When you retrieve them, how will you know what kind of object it is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an arraylist with multiple object types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602601/create-an-arraylist-with-multiple-object-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vytenis' answer is technically correct, but not something you should be doing on a regular basis. A more extensible solution is to create an interface and have both objects implement, letting the list hold both objects without losing the safety and advantages that normally come with statically typed lists.  While Java does not like multiple inheritance from classes, implementing multiple interfaces is no problem.

For example, take your class declarations:

```
class Object1{
    ...
}
...
class Object2{
    ...
}
```

and add the following interface declaration at the top level somewhere -

```
public interface SharedType{
     ...
}
```

for each object you want to store, have it implement the interface like this:

```
public class Object1 implements SharedType{
    ...
}
```

When you declare your list, declare it like this:

```
List<SharedType> mylist = new ArrayList<SharedType>();
```

or whatever type of list you're trying to create, obviously it doesn't have to be an arraylist

This won't work for built in types or classes who's declaration you can't change

Using interfaces as types is common practice in Java, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html , for example

**Edit**

If you need to store different built in types (like Strings and Integers), as suggested in the comments, consider making a wrapper object around them. This is slightly cumbersome, but you're not able to easily change the declaration of built-in classes, and using a generic type like Object should be a last resort, as it subverts the very reason of requiring a type specification in the first place.

For example,

```
interface Wrapper{}

class StringWrapper extends Wrapper{
    String s;

    public StringWrapper(String s){
        this.s = s;
    }
}

class IntWrapper extends Wrapper{
    String i;

    public StringWrapper(Integer i){
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Someone looking at your code (including you, later on), will now know exactly what you were trying to use in your list. You also still get the advantages of Java's static typing

Comment: +1 - this is the correct way of doing things. If your program requires storing unrelated types in the same collection, you're designing something wrong.

Comment: But it doesn work for standard objects. If you have to store `String` and `Integer`in same `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<Object>`, there you will be able to store anything.

Comment: `List<Object>` is an interface and does not function on its own. Please add some clarification.

Comment: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();` 95% of times there's no reason to declare variable as ArrayList, List is sufficient.

Comment: Of course. Your answer doesn't state that, though. Also, types in construction of generic classes is discouraged in Java7.