# How to use Arraylist in two java class

Tags: java, arraylist

How to use arraylist if I have 2 java class. Login and profile. If 2 user logs in, after submit button it will go to another java class and then will display their name, age, address. Thank you so much

Comment: Then use `ArrayList<Object>` or use a common interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an ArrayList with multiple object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602601/create-an-arraylist-with-multiple-object-types)

Comment: You need to explain more clearly and in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Your Question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

What you might want to consider is the [service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). You could provide a simple service that is composed of the List and then given as a dependency to other classes.

```java
class ArrayListService {

    private final List<MyObject> list;

    public ArrayListService(ArrayList<MyObject> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<MyObject> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

One thing that might work is making the ArrayList `public` and `static`. This way you will be able to access it from anywhere in the application (i.e. any class).

[More on static](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static).

Comment: Viable solution but definitely not conventional or best practice.