# How can I store classes in Array/Arraylists/Lists whatever?

Tags: java, android, arrays, class, arraylist

Is it in Java possible to store `classes`...

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
```

...in `Arrays`/`ArrayLists`, somehow like this:

```
ArrayList<> classArray = new ArrayList();
classArray.add(class1);
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but how could it work?

Comment: Did you try [google: java arrays and collections of objects](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+arrays+and+collections+of+objects)?

Comment: Do you mean how to store *objects* of a certain class, or do you mean to ask how to store `Class` objects than represent a class?

Comment: no like an actual class, like class `Fragment1`, which displays a fragment. I want to store that whole Fragment class in a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. You just specify the type of objects you want to store when you create the array list:

```
ArrayList<Class1> classArray = ArrayList<Class1>();
classArray.add(class1);
```

Comment: But when there are variable multiple Classes, and I don't know which gets in the ArrayList?

Comment: You either need to make it generic Java object ArrayList<Object> or you need to create a wrapper around it. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602601/create-an-arraylist-with-multiple-object-types

Comment: It is possible to use List<Object>, but I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

**If the class can only be Class1**

```
ArrayList<Class1> list = new ArrayList<Class1>();
```

Above code won't allow any other class objects it can only store objects of type Class1

**If you want to store any class object**

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Object is a parent class of everything in java which is the reason why it can store object of any class

Comment: Let´s say I have that ArrayList with my class inside, which works fine. But now I want to change a fragment in a certain part of the application to another one, and the other one is the one in my ArrayList. How can I put that ArrayList in: `manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_one, new //ArrayList with Class//).commit();`  ?

Comment: manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_one, new ArrayList( listThatYouWantToPut)).commit();       And remember if you want to add type safety then use new ArrayList<Type>() else ArrayList()