# Through ArrayList is it possible to pass multiple data type? If yes then need a code to demonstrate a case

Tags: java, arraylist, types

i have multiple data type like eg. {10, 12.5, 20, 50, "abcd", xyz}
So, i want to pass these data type through ArrayList and then filter only the integer value.

If this can be done then can any of you please provide a sample code to demonstrate it.
If no, then what's the reason.

Thanks in advance

So, i assume that this can be done by creating an object of arraylist.
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList <>();
And then can add all these values using list.add();

But then in this how can we filter integer after adding the values is where i got stuck

Comment: I recommend checking this similar post about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602601/create-an-arraylist-with-multiple-object-types

Comment: You can try the ArrayList removeIf() method in Java for filtering values, or using the instanceof Integer: https://medium.com/javarevisited/filtering-a-java-collection-by-type-7c1d611d0d95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part of your problem is right, just create an `ArrayList<Object>`

Then, try this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Object o : list){
 try{
    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(o.toString()))
 }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    //optional code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you must indeed create a list which accepts both `String`s and `Integer`s. The only way is to indeed create a `List<Object>`.

In order to retrieve the integer values, you could just test whether the contained object is of a certain type:

```java
for (var element : list) {
    if (element instanceof Integer) {
        // Do something with the value
    }
}
```

Or using streams:

```java
list.stream()
    .filter(element -> element instanceof Integer)
    // or .filter(Integer.class::isInstance)
    .forEach(element -> {
        // Do something with the value
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Object> list= new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);// interger
    list.add(11.00);// Double
    list.add("Strings");//String
    System.out.println(list);
```